# SSIS Create Parent

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

New to SSIS (2k12).

Importing a csv file containing any new or changed PO Lines. My db has a PO master, and a POLine child, so if the PO is new, I need to insert a row into the master before loading up the child(ren). I may have half a dozen children in the POLineDetail import.

To create a Master, I have to match up the ProjectNbr from the tblProjects table to get the ProjectID, similarly with the Vendor (VendorName and VendorID...) I can do this in T-SQL, but I'm not sure how best to do it using SSIS. What's the strategy?

Comment: New to SSIS (welcome!) but have you tried anything or done any research on the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the lookup transformation on the data flow task and route the unmatched records to the no match output. The no match output will be records that do not exist and need to be inserted, which you would attach to a destination transformation.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the first step that's needed is to load the data into a staging table so that you can work with the data. From there you can use the Lookup Transformations in SSIS to do the matching to populate your master data based on your mentioned criteria. You could also use the same lookup transformation with the CSV as the source without going into the table, but I like to stage the data so that there is an opportunity to do any additional cleanup that's needed. Either way though, the lookup transformation would provide the functionality that you're looking for.